# Como criar um Chronometer em uma notificação?

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte método abaixo:

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder createNotification(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    boolean running = true;
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentText("conteúdo")
            .setContentTitle("titulo")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_today_black_24dp)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setOngoing(running)
            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 10,
                            new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class)
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),
                            0)
            )
            .addAction(running ? R.drawable.ic_stop_black_24dp
                            : R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp,
                    running ? "Pause"
                            : "play",
                    pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stop_black_24dp, "Stop",
                    pIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    return builder;
}
```

No qual lança uma notificação na barra de status, como mostra abaixo na primeira notificação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para laçar a notificação faço desta forma:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = createNotification(this);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());
```

Gostaria de criar um `Chronometer` em uma notificação, exatamente como aparece na notificação do Strava (segunda notificação da imagem), como mostra acima.

Como criar um `Chronometer` em uma notificação?

Comment: @ramaral me dê um help! =)

Comment: Será que usando uma `RemoveView` não daria? Apesar de nunca ter usado eu chutaria que vale um teste.

Comment: @Wakim tentei de um jeito, pegando na web, mas apareceu que o método de inserção está depreciado. Vou pesquisar mais um pouco.

Comment: @Wakim repliquei a pergunta lá nos gringos, mas ainda não obtive resposta. =D

Comment: Concordo com o @Wakim. A classe RemoteViews permite usar uma view do tipo Chronometer. Veja [setChronometer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setChronometer(int,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean))

Comment: @ramaral eu cheguei mesmo a pesquisar sobre a classe `RemoteViews` e não `RemoveView`, e encontrei alguns resultados ontem mesmo. Acabei colocando uma resposta. Caso tenha alguma sugestão, ou discordância de algo, mê de um toque.

Comment: É isso. Agora só falta implementar os botões PAUSE e STOP :)

Comment: @ramaral sim, vou fazer isso, depois edito a resposta! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como questionado pelo @wakim, fiz uma breve busca sobre a classe `RemoteViews` no qual é possível usar o método [setChronometer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setChronometer(int,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) para criar uma notificação customizada. Veja abaixo como deve ficar:

**JAVA**

```
 RemoteViews remoteWidget = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
 remoteWidget.setChronometer(R.id.noteChronometer, value, null, true);

 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentText("")
            .setContentTitle("titulo")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_today_black_24dp)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 10,
                            new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class)
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),
                            0)
            );

 /* define customização da notificação*/
 builder.setCustomContentView(remoteWidget);

 notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

**XML:** `custom_notification.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/noteImageView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/noteImageView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/note_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#555555"
                    android:text="Tempo: " />

                <Chronometer
                    android:id="@+id/noteChronometer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#222222"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/noteImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_local_shipping_black_48dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]